# Application process not terminating after closing the application

Tags: c#, wpf

I modified an app the way I wanted. But seems like there is a small problem.
When I close it, the process associated with the app stays open and it's not terminating.
Yes, the RAM that it consumes decreases, but seems like something is not disposed of and this keeps the process running. How I can find what prevents the process from closing?
Its a program, written in C# WPF, which I modified by adding more windows, cycling between the windows, which open each other with

```
Form frm1=New Form()
this.Hide()
```

The second I close directly with

```
this.Close()
```

While before this I call other form.
The most simple way is to make it call batch that terminates the process on window closing. But I want to find out what is letting the process to terminate.

Comment: Probably you have not closed all open forms

Answer (score -1):

There Seems an instance is still running ( Not disposed the right way ) ...

Try to check  if frm1 and other Instanciated Forms are disposed well , else dispose them  on the **on the main Form's Exit event** .

```
if (!frm1.IsDisposed) frm1.Dispose();
```

do same to other instances .

Comment: The second form on exit disposes of all open resources, in this case camera by calling the function responsible for this and if there is any recording still running, calls the function for this. Then closes. If I close the second form from the X on the window, the process terminates. If I close the first form, without opening the second form, the process terminates. If I switch from the second form to the first and close the first, then the process does not terminate.